# Python printes unwanted letter after telling it not to

Tags: python

I wanted to create a translator, so I looked at some videos online and found one that showed how to substitute certain letters in a sentence and turn them into other letters/symbols. I tried doing it and it worked. But once I started adding new other letters for it to look for. It started printing the letter that was supposed to have been substituted.

```
def translate(phrase):
    translation = ""
    for letter in phrase:

        if letter in "ㅏ": #if ㅏ then A
            translation = translation + "A" 


        if letter in "Б": #if Б then B
            translation = translation + "B"
        else:
            translation = translation + letter

    return translation

print(translate(input("Enter a phrase: ")))
```

I am planning on adding the whole alphabet, so I can't have it print the unwanted "supposed to have been substituted letter". I have tried all I can. But I simply can't get it to work. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your else statemet is unconditional to the result of the first if statement.

Comment: Just create mapping of letters with simple dictionary and use it for every letter in phrase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to combine the `if` statements like so:

```
if letter in "ㅏ": #if ㅏ then A
    translation = translation + "A" 
elif letter in "Б": #if Б then B
    translation = translation + "B"
else:
    translation = translation + letter
```

Otherwise you'll be hitting the `else` branch for every character other than `Б` (and that includes `ㅏ`!)

It might be worth noting that `letter in "ㅏ"` can be written more simply as `letter == "ㅏ"`.  The same goes for the other comparison.

Finally, you might also want to take a look at `maketrans()` and `translate()`: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/string_maketrans.htm

Comment: Yeah... definitely looks like: `phrase.translate(str.maketrans('Бㅏ', 'AB'))` is the sensible approach here...